# Encrypted partition not accessible after resume

Tags: debian, lvm, suspend

I am using Debian Stretch on a laptop with a HDD (/dev/sda) and an SSD (/dev/sdd). My swap and home partitions are encrypted with lvm. The ouput of lsblk is:

```
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                          8:1    0   243M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                          8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                          8:5    0 931.3G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt                254:0    0 931.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─pc--117--162--vg-root   254:1    0 893.6G  0 lvm   /home
    └─pc--117--162--vg-swap_1 254:2    0  37.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                             8:16   0   477G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                          8:17   0   477G  0 part  /
```

For several weeks now I have been having issues after resume (both from RAM or from disk): my /home seems not to be accessible (at least for writing). This does not happen every time, but more something like once every 10 or 20 resume cycles.

At first, I thought this was related to an initramfs-tools (0.129) update where it was mentioned that the RESUME variable had to be set in the configuration, but this should only affect resuming from disk. I however tried to set this to different values (the /dev/XXX, auto, none) but nothing changes with my issue.

Since I also have a warning at boot time saying "Failing to connect to lvmetad" I set use_lvmetad = 0 in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf. Again, nothing changes.

My /etc/crypttab reads as follows:

```
sda5_crypt UUID=11a52b25-26f4-41ae-b52e-2aa5d0a4d35d none luks
```

which seems OK since

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 31 10:45 11a52b25-26f4-41ae-b52e-2aa5d0a4d35d -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 31 10:45 136599d4-9b3b-4a74-a0dc-6bc48fb227f3 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 31 10:45 2b70ec10-751f-4670-8000-1c59d7307f29 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 31 10:45 98ae6177-1de0-4af2-b905-687df457f1ca -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 31 10:45 d3415b5d-e1fe-4ce6-98c8-a8645f358524 -> ../../dm-1
```

Anybody can help?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the modules you have configured at `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`? . Basically you need to add the `dm_crypt` module to that file, and at `/etc/default/grub`, at the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line add your swap partition with the resume directive: `"... resume=/dev/MyStorage/swap"`

Comment: Thanks. Does "resume=/dev/mapper/pc--117--162--vg-swap_1" seem OK? I am however surprised that most of the time it OK works without and the changes you suggest.

Comment: Yes. That is what you need to configure. When you resumed OK without with this configuration, you knew if it was resuming from ram or disk?

Comment: It worked with both RAM and disk. As I wrote in my question, only once in a while, the issue happens.

Comment: OK. I had the feeling that it could happen when a "suspend to ram" got transformed into "suspend to disk" after X minutes. Maybe what you are facing is a bug... and not a misconfiguration. Just don't know what you should enable to increase debug in this situation.